# Focus an input field after appending with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I want to append an input field on click, and focus it so that it has a blinking cursor and can be typed directly. With the following code I am able to append it but i doesn't focus. I first need to click on the field and then I can type.

How can I append and focus?

I have tried following line but it doesn't do anything

```
$('.fields').append(field_html).focus();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fields">
<!-- append here -->
</div>    

<div class="row">
<input name="input" class="input">
</div>

<button>Add</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
  var field_html = $('.row').html();    
  $('.fields').append(field_html);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.input{
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
 $('button').on('click', function(e){
      var field_html = $('.row').html();    
      $('.fields').append(field_html);
    });
```

```css
 .input{
      padding: 10px 10px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      width: 300px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .row {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields">
    <!-- append here -->
    </div>    
    
    <div class="row">
    <input name="input" class="input">
    </div>
    
    <button>Add</button>
```

**JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/sLob7cwh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e){
  var field_html = $('.row').html();    
  $('.fields').append(field_html).find('input:last').focus();
});
```

```css
 .input{
      padding: 10px 10px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      width: 300px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .row {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields">
<!-- append here -->
</div>    

<div class="row">
<input name="input" class="input">
</div>

<button>Add</button>
```

this code works and will add focus to the latest added input

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
  var field_html = $('.row').html();    
  $('.fields').append(field_html).find('input:last').focus();
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzhgbjt8/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ztnoLf4h/

Answer (score 1):

JQuery methods generally chain the collections, in the case of `.append` it passes through the original collection.

Instead, you can use `.appendTo` which passes through the new html (as it's the original collection)

Change

```
var container = $("container").append("new_html");
```

to

```
var newElements = $("new_html").appendTo("container");
```

You can then use that result going forward, so your code becomes:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
  var field_html = $('.row').html();    
  $(field_html).appendTo(".fields").find("input.input").focus();
});
```